# QgsVectorLayer error empty

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I try to develop an app using QGIS Api. My code looks like this (it's an app with a gui) :

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

qgs.initQgis()

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:\projects\files\Test_polygone.shp", "Test Polygones", "ogr")

if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
```

Each paths are good. No problem for there. I can't debug it because when i try to read vlayer.error().message(), it's an empty string.

Have someone an idea why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to properly take care of escaping in strings.

Basically `\` is used as escape characters. You either need to replace it with `/` in your path which is unproblematic wrt escaping. Or use `\\` or use `r"C:\yourpath"` to specify that it's a raw string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But both solutions doesn't work. I've try to check if it's a file and for my shape file, it return True. For the QGis directory, the path is good too. :(

Comment: Can you adjust the question with the updated code?